# to count the number of occurrence of an element with specific attribute and specific value in xml

Tags: xml, linq, xpath

i am using linq to xml along with xpath to get the number of occurrence of a element with a specific attribute and specific value....here is my xml file...
in this i have to extract the number of occurrence of element p with attribute "HSDPACodeCapacity" and with value 5....this is a very long file so i dint post this completely......help pls ......i want to use LINQ to xml to program it
"

```
<managedObject class="WBTS" version="RN6.0_2.0" distName="PLMN-PLMN/RNC-3003/WBTS-2743" id="214999014">
  <defaults name="System"/>
  <p name="DLCECapacity">0</p>
  <p name="HSDPACodeCapacity">5</p>
  <p name="ULCECapacity">0</p>
  <p name="bburruFlag">0</p>
  <p name="name">WHALANoO</p>
  <p name="nbrRepeater">0</p>
  <p name="numFa">1</p>
  <p name="type">3</p>
  <p name="BTSAdditionalInfo">150.78892:-33.76300</p>
  <p name="BTSIPAddress">10.212.19.121</p>
  <p name="BTSSupportForHSPACM">1</p>
  <p name="COCOId">2743</p>
  <p name="DCNLinkStatus">1</p>
  <p name="DCNSecurityStatus">0</p>
  <p name="DLORLAveragingWindowSize">0</p>
  <p name="DSCPHigh">46</p>
  <p name="DSCPLow">0</p>
  <p name="DSCPMedDCH">34</p>
  <p name="DediMeasRepPeriodCSdata">3</p>
  <p name="DediMeasRepPeriodPSdata">1</p>
  <p name="DedicatedMeasReportPeriod">5</p>
  <p name="DelayThresholdMax">10000</p>
  <p name="DelayThresholdMax2msTTI">10000</p>
  <p name="DelayThresholdMid">7000</p>
  <p name="DelayThresholdMid2msTTI">7000</p>
  <p name="DelayThresholdMin">5000</p>
  <p name="DelayThresholdMin2msTTI">5000</p>
  <p name="HARQRVConfiguration">1</p>
  <p name="HSDPA14MbpsPerUser">1</p>
  <p name="HSDPACCEnabled">1</p>
  <p name="HSDPAULCToDSCP">34</p>
  <p name="HSUPADLCToDSCP">34</p>
  <p name="HSUPAXUsersEnabled">60</p>
  <p name="IPBasedRouteIdIub">0</p>
  <p name="IPBasedRouteIdIub2">0</p>
  <p name="IPNBId">0</p>
  <p name="IntelligentSDPrioHO">0</p>
  <p name="IubTransportMedia">0</p>
  <p name="LoadControlPeriodPS">4</p>
  <p name="MaxNumberEDCHLCG">80</p>
  <p name="MeasFiltCoeff">4</p>
  <p name="MinUDPPortIub">1026</p>
  <p name="NBAPCommMode">0</p>
  <p name="NESWVersion">WN7.0_1.0</p>
  <p name="NEType">3</p>
  <p name="NbrOfOverbookedHSDPAUsers">3</p>
  <p name="PDUSize656WithHSDSCH">2</p>
  <p name="PSAveragingWindowSize">5</p>
  <p name="PSRLAveragingWindowSize">0</p>
  <p name="ProbabilityFactorMax">1000</p>
  <p name="ProbabilityFactorMax2msTTI">1000</p>
  <p name="PrxAlpha">40</p>
  <p name="PrxMeasAveWindow">20</p>
  <p name="PrxTargetPSAdjustPeriod">10</p>
  <p name="PtxAlpha">20</p>
  <p name="PtxDPCHmax">-30</p>
  <p name="PtxDPCHmin">-30</p>
  <p name="PtxMeasAveWindow">20</p>
  <p name="RACHloadIndicationPeriod">1</p>
  <p name="RRIndPeriod">20</p>
  <p name="RRMULDCHActivityFactorCSAMR">50</p>
  <p name="RRMULDCHActivityFactorCSNTData">95</p>
  <p name="RRMULDCHActivityFactorCSTData">100</p>
  <p name="RRMULDCHActivityFactorPSBackgr">60</p>
  <p name="RRMULDCHActivityFactorPSStream">95</p>
  <p name="RRMULDCHActivityFactorPSTHP1">60</p>
  <p name="RRMULDCHActivityFactorPSTHP2">60</p>
  <p name="RRMULDCHActivityFactorPSTHP3">60</p>
  <p name="RRMULDCHActivityFactorSRB">1</p>
  <p name="ReleaseTimerForSharedHSDPAallocation">3</p>
  <p name="SchedulingPeriod">200</p>
  <p name="SharedHSDPAVCCSelectionMethod">0</p>
  <p name="SharedHSDPAallocation">25</p>
  <p name="ToAWEOffsetNRTDCHIP">5</p>
  <p name="ToAWEOffsetRTDCHIP">0</p>
  <p name="ToAWSOffsetNRTDCHIP">10</p>
  <p name="ToAWSOffsetRTDCHIP">10</p>
  <p name="WBTSChangeOrigin">2</p>
  <p name="WBTSName">WHALANoO</p>
  <p name="WinACRABsetupDL">5</p>
  <p name="WinACRABsetupUL">5</p>
  <p name="WinLCHSDPA">5</p>
  <p name="WinLCHSUPA">5</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is your XPATH to achive this:

```
count(//p[@name='HSDPACodeCapacity'][.='5'])
```